# How to translate the UI of TWTweetComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

In the UI of the TWTweetComposeViewController, there are two buttons at the top of the alert, cancel and send, and even if the language of my phone is set to another language than english, these two buttons are still in english.

I tried to find how to change these text but I can't find how.

Do you any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a localization omission by Apple.

Comment: Just checked: they do get translated here. Ensure that your iOS device is up to date and that you have restarted it after changing your language settings (it helps). Like most built-in options, you cannot change much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option: [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController)

It's open source, so you can make any changes you need to.